# Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

Tags: java, exception

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dklDG.png)

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGMIK.png)

Here is the code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkKjQ.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19MI0.png)

Comment: I am facing above exception while generating token . Can someone please help why I am getting this exception ,if anything is wrong in code? But when I am using ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails token is getting generated successfully.

Comment: but same way when I am doing with ClientCredentialResourceDetails i am facing this unauthorized exception

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of giving code snippets like this in images, you could have pasted the code as well as exceptions, so it would be easy to read and understand, just a thought

Comment: Anyways resolved...secrets was going wrong